# Android Convert DatePicker generated date to a SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, datepicker, simpledateformat

I just implemented a DatePicker for my app. But I'm having a hard time understanding how to convert it('theDate') to a SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z") just like the ('submitDate') in my code below.

Could someone kindly show me how to do it in my code please? Thank you!

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case SDATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, 
            sDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);        
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener sDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, 
            int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;                                
                updateDate();
            }
    };

    private void updateDate() {
        inputDate.setText(
            new StringBuilder()                
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));                
    }


    class CreateNewRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");

            String submitDate = sd.format(c.getTime());

            String theDate = inputDate.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request_date", theDate));            
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submitDate", submitDate));

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1) You need to parse `theDate` to Date object using `SimpleDateFormatter`

You may need separate `SimpleDateFormatter` for above step, the one you have already works for below step only.

Your thisDate is formatted with hyphen as separator, so your SimpleDateFormatter for step1 should use hyphen:

Example:  `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");`

Step2) Pass Date object constructed in above step as input instead of c.getTime(), then you will get formatted date as you want.

EDIT:

```
String theDate = inputDate.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat firstFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
try {
      Date date = firstFormatter .parse(theDate );
      SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
      String submitDate = sd.format(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: See this example, which almost same like your requirementhttp://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm, instead of hardcoded string in parse(..), you need to pass thisDate.

Comment: Thank you Nambari, but could you give me the link again? it looks like a bad link..

Comment: well..i'm not getting it still.. I guess i really need someone to guide me with some example since i'm new to java..

Comment: @nana: May I know what exactly you are not getting? can you update your latest code.

Comment: I wasn't able to write any code because I don't understand from the example link..Could you simply show me kindly? My brain went blank right now..

Comment: @nana: Edited my answer to add some example. There may be syntax errors, but that is how you need to do.